# Thymeleaf EL expression generates link with /?param=value instead of /value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a link template in my emailTemplate.html which looks like this:

```
<span>To edit the invoice <a th:href="@{${editAddress}(invoiceid=${invoiceid})}">click here</a></span>
```

And produces:

http://localhost:8080/edit/?invoiceid=5d088b012f8c32416dbb5522

But I'd like to have:

http://localhost:8080/edit/5d088b012f8c32416dbb5522

My Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{invoiceid}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String editInvoice(@PathVariable("invoiceid") String invoiceid, Model model) {
    InvoiceData invoiceData = invoiceDataRepository.findById(invoiceid).get();
    model.addAttribute("invoicedata", invoiceData);
    return "edit";
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a bit, I have changed

```
<a th:href="@{${editAddress}(invoiceid=${invoiceid})}">click here</a>
```

to

```
<a th:href="@{{editAddress}{invoiceid}(invoiceid=${invoiceid},editAddress=${editAddress})}">click here</a>
```

And everything works fine now, the output is:

```
http://localhost:8080/edit/5d088b012f8c32416dbb5522
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this :

```
<span>To edit the invoice 
     <a th:href="@{${edit_address + '/' + invoice_id}}">click here</a>
</span>
```

Assuming edit_address = 'edit' and invoice_id = 5d088b012f8c32416dbb5522 the link will point to http://localhost:8080/edit/5d088b012f8c32416dbb5522